How to remove Shrine non existing locally images from model
I loaded db dump for my project.
Every Member has avatar_data (a shrine image) but i don't have those images locally.
I want to clean up Members and remove all attachments and all images.
How to remove all images from models that has Shrine::AvatarAttachment?
My Member model has
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  include Member::AvatarUploader::Attachment(:avatar)

So every member.avatar gives me this
irb(main):084> m.avatar
=> #<Member::AvatarUploader::UploadedFile storage=:store id="member/672/avatar/3d482ea33c71f62e17b53b67a7cca73d.png" metadata={"size"=>1363403, "filename"=>"Screenshot 2024-06-08 at 12.35.39.png", "mime_type"=>"image/png"}>

I tried
Member.update(avatar: nil)
but
irb(main):089> m.update(avatar: nil)
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Member Exists? (3.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."external_id" = $1 AND "members"."id" != $2 AND "members"."company_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["external_id", "1313"], ["id", 672], ["company_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Member Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."external_id" = $1 AND "members"."id" != $2 AND "members"."company_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["external_id", "1313"], ["id", 672], ["company_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
/Users/kanvull/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/shrine-3.5.0/lib/shrine/attacher.rb:322:in `file!': no file is attached (Shrine::Error)

there is no file it has to remove

.destroy? https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/activerecord#after-destroy
